# MasterDetail + Right-to-Left in Xamarin.Forms v3

Tags: xamarin.forms, right-to-left, master-detail

I'm using new forms feature Right-to-Left, it works well except MasterDetail hamburger menu icon. It stays on the left side and I need to move it to right whem localization is changed. Any ideas or could somebody help me with custom renderer?

Comment: from the images, it looks like menu of the masterdetail is RTL.https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/1222

Comment: @Ali123 look at top navbar... icons are on same position (for example arrow)... it should be on the right side wehen its rtl

Comment: Is there any way to doing that by custom renderer?

Comment: everywere I found that it is inpossible to make (now) hope they will fix it

Comment: it's possible now (I think they fixed it in one of the latest updates), just add the required permissions: https://blog.xamarin.com/right-to-left-localization-xamarin-forms/
read the "Preparing for Right-to-Left" part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well not impossible but some dirty coding is needed:

[please check the solution here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2818#issuecomment-393547500)

as recap:
To force the layout RTL and LTR on IOS:

1- Create this class/service

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using yourproject.iOS;
using yourproject.database;
using ObjCRuntime;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UIKit;
using System.Diagnostics;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PathManager_IOS))]
namespace yourproject.iOS
{
 public class PathManager_IOS : IPathManager
 {
[DllImport(ObjCRuntime.Constants.ObjectiveCLibrary, EntryPoint = "objc_msgSend")]
internal extern static IntPtr IntPtr_objc_msgSend(IntPtr receiver, IntPtr selector, UISemanticContentAttribute arg1);

    public PathManager_IOS()
    {

    }
   public void SetLayoutRTL()
    {
        try
        {
            Selector selector = new Selector("setSemanticContentAttribute:");
            IntPtr_objc_msgSend(UIView.Appearance.Handle, selector.Handle, UISemanticContentAttribute.ForceRightToLeft);
        }
        catch (Exception s)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("failed to set layout...."+s.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
    public void SetLayoutLTR()
    {
        try
        {
            Selector selector = new Selector("setSemanticContentAttribute:");
            IntPtr_objc_msgSend(UIView.Appearance.Handle, selector.Handle, UISemanticContentAttribute.ForceLeftToRight);
        }
        catch (Exception s)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("failed to set layout...." + s.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
 }
}
```

ps: please change "yourproject" to your project name...

To Call this on startup

in AppDelegate.cs

```
   PathManager_IOS pathManager = new PathManager_IOS();
   if (lang == 3)
    {
      pathManager.SetLayoutRTL();/* RTL */

    }
    if (lang == 1||lang == 2)
    {
       pathManager.SetLayoutLTR();/*   LTR   */
    }
    LoadApplication(new App(m, lang));
```

TO call this from the PCL shared pages or project

```
/* arabic */
DependencyService.Get<IPathManager>().SetLayoutRTL();

/* English */
DependencyService.Get<IPathManager>().SetLayoutLTR();
```

[image: English - hamburger menu icon on the LEFT.]
[image: ARABIC - hamburger menu icon on the RIGHT.]

Don't forget to set the flow direction on language change

```
if(lang==3)
                {//arabic 
                    this.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
                    this.Master.FlowDirection= FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
                    this.Detail.FlowDirection= FlowDirection.RightToLeft;

                }
```

hope this helps! all this for that hamburger icon !!!

Cheers, 
Rabih

Answer (score 0):

To force Android navigation Bar to be RTL use masterDetailPage renderer on Android project something like this:

```
public class MyMasterDetailPageRenderer : MasterDetailPageRenderer
{
    public MyMasterDetailPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {


    }
    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        toolbar.LayoutDirection = LayoutDirection.Rtl;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

the first step is to set master direction flow

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="APPNAME.MainPage"
                  FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
```

and for Android you need to add `android:supportsRtl="true"` to AndroidManifest.xml like

```
<application android:label="APPNAME.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
```

and then your master page is rtl as well as the action bar.

[image]
[image]